# COM-Interop: Change .NET Framework Version from 2.0 to 4.0 - Should I change the Guids also?

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex, com-interop

I like to migrate a COM-Class from 2.0 to 4.0. Would you recommend also to generate new guids for the classes and a different ProgId?

The old Class would not be used anymore. I know I have to re-register the Class, for the new Path of the mscorlib.

MS-Access create an instance auf my COM-Server Class with CreateObject and my COM-Object load some other classes with DI (dot.net 2.0 and in future 4.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have to use new GUIDs when the interface definition changes.  When you keep them the same, your new COM server will *replace* the existing one.  And client code that uses it doesn't have to be recompiled.  When you *do* change them then they can live side-by-side but client code has to explicitly be recompiled to use the new one.

Note that the in-process side-by-side CLR version support in .NET 4.0 is relevant here.  Your COM server can be used in a program that binds the .NET 4.0 CLR, even if the COM server still binds the 2.0 CLR.  Technically you don't have to update it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the side-by-side tip is nice, because of my DI with NET 2.0. I have to change the installer because in the Registry there was the reference to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would change the Guid or the progid.  It means you would have to recompile everything that this references.

As long as you stick to **binary compatability**, it doesn't matter what version of the framework the *implementation* of your contract is, it's simply that, an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated to DOT.net 4.0 and do some tests.
DOT.net 4.0 can use 2.0 Assemblies, no problem for my DI Scenario.

The Only thing I have to do, is update my installer. The reason for this is, because the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{COMGuid} controls witch Runtime Version it have to use.

"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"